# Round imageview in collectionviewcell

Tags: objective-c, ios8, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

i am working on uicollectionview. i want customize cell so i took separate class file for cell. i took an image in cell from storyboard. my problem is i want rounding image but image shape convert to be diamond. please suggest me the way to convert this diamond image into to circle.

see here

[image]

UICollectionView in storyboard

[image]

```
ViewController.h

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property(nonatomic, weak)IBOutlet UICollectionView *my_collectionview;
@end

ViewController.m

@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize my_collectionview;


- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView{
    return 1;
}


-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
return 9;
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    CollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CollectionViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

return cell;
}

CollectionViewCell.h

@interface CollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell
@property(nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIImageView *temp_imgview;
@end


CollectionViewCell.m

-(void)awakeFromNib{
    [temp_imgview.layer setCornerRadius:self.temp_imgview.frame.size.width/2];
    temp_imgview.layer.borderWidth=0.5;
    temp_imgview.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    temp_imgview.clipsToBounds=YES;
}
```

if i put hard code 100 instead of `self.temp_imgview.frame.size.width/2` then it is working. can anybody help me how can i solve this

Comment: Are you using Size Classes? Show us the temp_imgview's constraints

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your constraints in the storyboard, the `awakeFromNib` might not be the correct place to all the rounded corners. That is because it might be that the frame of the `imageView` is not final there.

You could try adding the code for the rounded corners in `layoutSubviews`. Something like this:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    [temp_imgview.layer setCornerRadius:self.temp_imgview.frame.size.width/2];
    temp_imgview.layer.borderWidth=0.5;
    temp_imgview.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    temp_imgview.clipsToBounds=YES;

}
```

Also, in your `awakeFromNib`, you missed the `super` call.

Let me know if this worked out for you or need more help! Good luck

---

**Update**

You could try using the size of the image, instead of the frame. Something like this:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    [temp_imgview.layer setCornerRadius:self.temp_imgview.image.size.width/2];
    temp_imgview.layer.borderWidth=0.5;
    temp_imgview.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    temp_imgview.clipsToBounds=YES;

}
```

If this does not work either, try logging the frame of your image on iPhone and iPad to see what differs between them

Comment: thank you catalina for replay....i tried your code but same thing happened....my code is working fine for iphone while its not working in ipad where i took only the dublicate sotryboard of iphone for ipad.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding [self layoutIfNeeded], it worked for me.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    [self layoutIfNeeded];
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = CGRectGetWidth(imageView.bounds) / 2;
    imageView.layer.borderWidth = 0.1;
    imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
}
```